# Using several subqueries in sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, subquery

I am trying to use several subqueries but I am getting an error. It works if I remove the second subquery.

Error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
USE SUPERSTARIS
    SELECT lines.Item,
        Inventory.ItemAlternative,
        Inventory.OnHandPhys,
        Inventory.Allocated,
        Inventory.CostPrice,
        replace(vInventoryOptional2Values.Value, '/', '') AS Brand,
        Inventory.Optional3 AS StockStatus,
        (SELECT SUM(l.Invoiced) * -1
            FROM lines l
            WHERE l.Date >= '2014-01-01'
                AND l.Date <= '2014-01-31'
                AND l.Item = lines.Item) AS QtySoldInPeriod,
        (SELECT SUM(lines.AmountBase-lines.CostAmount)*-1
            FROM lines l
            WHERE l.Date >= '2014-01-01'
                AND l.Date <= '2014-01-31'
                AND l.Item = lines.Item) AS QtySoldInPeriod2
    FROM lines
    INNER JOIN inventory ON lines.item = Inventory.item
    INNER JOIN vInventoryOptional2Values ON Inventory.Optional2 = vInventoryOptional2Values.RecordID
    WHERE lines.Invoiced < 0
        AND Inventory.Status = 0
        AND Inventory.Optional3 <> 3
    GROUP BY Lines.Item,
        Inventory.Optional3,
        Inventory.ItemAlternative,
        Inventory.OnHandPhys,
        Inventory.CostPrice,
        vInventoryOptional2Values.Value,
        Inventory.Allocated
```

Comment: Well its exactly what the error says... just read it...

Comment: Issue is in here `SUM(lines.AmountBase-lines.CostAmount)` (your second subquery)use the alias as `SUM(l.AmountBase-l.CostAmount)`

Comment: A subquery with `sum()` and no `group by` should always return a single row. Are you sure this is the exact query that gives the "returned more than 1 value" error?

Comment: @Andomar see the comment of Coder of Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Coder of Code wrote, the error is you reference the main query table in the subquery instead of the subquery table. So you can quickly correct your error.
But you already group by lines.item in the main query, so you do not need extra subqueries to get the SUMs.

you can simplify your query - remove subqueries:

```
USE SUPERSTARIS
SELECT lines.Item,
    Inventory.ItemAlternative,
    Inventory.OnHandPhys,
    Inventory.Allocated,
    Inventory.CostPrice,
    replace(vInventoryOptional2Values.Value, '/', '') AS Brand,
    Inventory.Optional3 AS StockStatus,
    -SUM(lines.Invoiced) AS QtySoldInPeriod,
    -SUM(lines.AmountBase-lines.CostAmount) AS QtySoldInPeriod2
FROM lines
INNER JOIN inventory ON lines.item = Inventory.item
INNER JOIN vInventoryOptional2Values ON Inventory.Optional2 = vInventoryOptional2Values.RecordID
WHERE lines.Invoiced < 0
    AND lines.Date >= '2014-01-01'
    AND lines.Date <= '2014-01-31'
    AND Inventory.Status = 0
    AND Inventory.Optional3 <> 3
GROUP BY Lines.Item,
    Inventory.Optional3,
    Inventory.ItemAlternative,
    Inventory.OnHandPhys,
    Inventory.CostPrice,
    vInventoryOptional2Values.Value,
    Inventory.Allocated
```

and do further optimizations:

```
USE SUPERSTARIS
SELECT Inventory.Item,
    Inventory.ItemAlternative,
    Inventory.OnHandPhys,
    Inventory.Allocated,
    Inventory.CostPrice,
    replace(vInventoryOptional2Values.Value, '/', '') AS Brand,
    Inventory.Optional3 AS StockStatus,
    l.QtySoldInPeriod,
    l.QtySoldInPeriod2
FROM (
    SELECT lines.item,
        -SUM(lines.Invoiced) AS QtySoldInPeriod,
        SUM(lines.CostAmount - lines.AmountBase) AS QtySoldInPeriod2
    FROM lines
    WHERE lines.Invoiced < 0
        AND lines.Date >= '2014-01-01'
        AND lines.Date <= '2014-01-31'
    GROUP BY Lines.Item) l
INNER JOIN inventory ON l.item = Inventory.item
    AND Inventory.Status = 0
    AND Inventory.Optional3 <> 3
INNER JOIN vInventoryOptional2Values ON Inventory.Optional2 = vInventoryOptional2Values.RecordID
```

Comment: btw your original query must have returned lot of rows with 0 SUMs, because you return the items out of the defined date range too